# static variable = local temporary variable then return in c# - is this safe?

Tags: c#, variables, static, local, assign

I'm new to object oriented code, and I have a question if this code is safe.
I have a local List "TempCand" that is assigned to a static member List "Candidates" of the class. When I leave the search method, I fear that the memory of my local variable is subject to garbage collection, which would then affect my static variable. Or is this ok?

```
public class search
{
    class candidate
    {
        // ...
    }
    static List <candidate> Candidates = new List <candidate>();

    static public void clean_Candidates()
    {
        List <candidate> TempCand = new List <candidate>();
        // ...
        // copy some elements of Candidates in clean_Candidates()
        // ...
        Candidates = TempCand;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem from a GC standpoint, but I do see one from a thread-safe standpoint. The code you've written doesn't look thread safe.

Comment: @RonBeyer it's perfectly possible that this is part of a thread-safe class, depending on how other methods using `Candidates` work.

Comment: Stop worrying; you can trust the GC. Its only job is to make sure that stuff stays alive as long as it needs to, and gets cleaned up later.

Comment: @JonHanna Its possible there is much more to this, however all we can do is comment on code provided instead of speculate on code that's not. As its written, without seeing what is "between the lines", its not thread safe.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If there is a way for you to tell that a specific object was collected, that object won't be collected.  So, any time you say, "I'm worried that X will be collected and cause problem Y," then you can be assured that X will not be collected because Y would allow you to notice.  Counterexamples mostly only apply to very advanced techniques (e.g, use of the `WeakReference` class).   I suppose one could also argue that collection of finalizers is observable, but that's almost as obvious as `WeakReference` collection being observable (and finalizers are an advanced technique, imo).

Comment: @RonBeyer from what's in the code given, it is threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

> I fear that the memory of my local variable is subject to garbage collection

One of the things that means something can't be garbage collected, is that there is an in-use local variable that references it.

> which would then affect my static variable

Another of the things that means something can't be garbage collected, is that there is a static field that references it.

Local variables themselves aren't something that garbage collection affects at all; at some point when the method isn't using it (which may be when the scope is left, or may be before then) the local memory can just be re-used for something else. You pretty much will never care, because if you ever go to use it, then by definition you aren't at a point where it will never be used (there's an exception around timers and weak references, but you're using neither here).

Now, **if** that local variable is a reference type, then it could have been something that was keeping the object referenced alive. However, that again won't generally be visible, because this is only if it's the **only** reference to this object.

When the garbage collector kicks in, the first thing it does is to find all the things it **can't** collect:

1. Anything in a local variable that is in use.
2. Anything in a static field.
3. Anything in a field of an object the above two rules have said can't be collected.
4. Anything in a field that rule 3 said can't be collected, applying this rule recursively.

If you can "see" it, the GC can't collect it.

GC can't affect your static field, because by definition, being in a static field makes it off-limits.

Answer (score 0):

`TempCand` and `Candidates` are references toward some data (a list of  `Candidate` objects, in this case). Of course, you can create and destroy additional references without affecting the objects at all.

So, one possible scenario is this:

1. You create the `Candidates` list and put in 5 `Candidate` objects inside.
   As the objects are referenced by the list, and the list is referenced by the static property, the objects will not be garbage collected.
2. You call the `CleanCandidates` static method. Within it, you create another reference (`tempCand`) to a list of candidates. You add references to three of the `Candidate` objects to the new list.
3. If a garbage run occurs it this moment, none of the `Candidate` objects will be collected, as they are still referenced from the static list.
4. You set that the static `Candidates` property now points to the new list and exit the method. If a garbage run occurs now, it can collect

   - The old list that `Candidates` used to reference. It's not referenced by anything now.
   - The two `Candidate` objects that were in the old list, but not in the new list, as there is nothing that references them now.
   - The `tempCand` reference, as it is out of scope - the method is finished, and a new reference will be created if it is called again. Note that the list that `tempCand` references will not be collected, as it's available now through the `Candidates` static field. (Note that collection of local fields is usually done "magically" with stack rewind)

So, the candidates you want alive will be (and stay alive) and the candidates that you threw out will eventually be garbage collected (if not referenced by some other, not shown code).

---

That said, the code shown is not thread safe. You could potentially execute `CleanCandidates` twice, and wreak havoc on the collection. You have to be very, very careful as your static list is effectively shared application state.